# Math Statistics Bell Curve Computing % correct given 2 numbers (C#)

Tags: c#, logarithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computing per cent correctness from a bell curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16968/computing-per-cent-correctness-from-a-bell-curve)

I've been trying to remember my High School teachings and are falling short.

I'm working on a project where I need to give a % of correctness for an integer (How close a given number is to the actual number within a 300% difference).  For example if real number is 50, any number from -100 to 150 will return > 0% correctness.

The problem is that we need a curve (log, or bell curve, or something similar) to return a non-linear % correctness (i.e. 100 is 50% correct in linear terms, but we would want maybe 66%? ... and 125 is 33%?) and I dont have a formula to get this response.

Something like this (sorry, used mspaint quickly to try to explain)
[image: Example]

Am I explaining this properly?  Make sense?  Any help?  ;)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called "standard deviation".  http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html

Comment: Yep, I ran into standard deviation too, just its a bit complicated for me to process right now.  If you understand it, can you throw me a formula? :)

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is a standard mathematical concept.  Maybe if you can explain why you need this, we can recognize the concept you are thinking of.